# Android: Dynamically Generated Views added but not shown

Tags: android

I have a UI component with this format:

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/item_lists"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/first_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:text="First List"/>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/first_list"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="10dp" >

        </ListView>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

The outer RelativeLayout is the wrapper which I plan to dynamically generate views and inject into, the logic to dynamically add views (a text title and another listview):

```
private void populateLists() {
    View pre = firstList; // this points to the list view "list_view"
    if(!titleMap.isEmpty()) { // titleMap is a hashmap that maps titles to lists
        Set<String> titles = getTitles();

        for(String title : titles){
                List<Item> li = titleMap.get(title);
                TextView tag = generateTitleTextView(title, pre);
                ListView lv = generateListView(li, tag);
                sceneLists.addView(tag);
                sceneLists.addView(lv);

                pre = lv;
            }
       }

}
```

`generateTitleTextView(String title, View pre)` and `generateListView(List<Item> list, View pre)` are two methods that generate views and place the generated view under View component pre by using

```
layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, pre.getId());
```

The code can run without exceptions, but the generated views are not visible on the page, I wonder what might be the issue? Thanks in advance!

Edit: The code for generateTitleTextView, generateListView is similar only difference is it generates a ListView

```
private TextView generateTitleTextView(String title, View pre) {
    TextView tag = new TextView(this);
    tag.setId(generateRandomViewId());// generates a random int as Id
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, pre.getId());
    tag.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

    tag.setText(title);

    return tag;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you generate the `viewId`? 
You can use [HierarchyViewer](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/hierarchy-viewer.html) or turn on `Show layout bounds` in Developer Options to debug this.

I think you should try generate view ids with this piece of code:

```java
public static int generateViewId() {
   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        for (; ; ) {
            final int result = sNextGeneratedId.get();
            // aapt-generated IDs have the high byte nonzero; clamp to the range under that.
            int newValue = result + 1;
            if (newValue > 0x00FFFFFF) {
                newValue = 1; // Roll over to 1, not 0.
            }
            if (sNextGeneratedId.compareAndSet(result, newValue)) {
                return result;
            }
        }
    } else {
        return View.generateViewId();
    }
}
```

Comment: I generate viewId using hashcode of a random UUID. I guess that would not be a problem? I will try debugging per your suggestions, thank you!

Comment: I think the code you suggested is using the logic of the implementation of View.generateViewId(), it did not help with my situation.